# Are abelian schemes flat?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

> Let $\pi: \mathcal A \to S$ be an abelian scheme, i.e. a proper,
>   smooth group scheme over a scheme $S$ whose geometric fibers are connected and
>   of dimension $g$. Is $\pi$ necessarily flat? What is the proof/reference?

**Motivation:** say we are given an Artinian local ring $R$ with the residue field $k$. The deformation theory is interested in seeking for **flat** liftings of varieties $X/k$ to $R$. However, when lifting abelian varieties (e.g. Serre-Tate theory) one doesn't mention flatness.

This question bothers me, since it is something I should already know by now...

Comment: By definition a smooth morphism is flat.

Comment: silly me! of course. this ends the problem